# playframework 2.x with scala - How to show logger info from specs2 running test?

Tags: testing, logging, playframework-2.0, specs2

I did a couple of simple tests using specs2, and I inserted several play.Logger.info("messsage") in it, but they just don't appear anywhere...

Is there some way to enable them to be shown somewhere?

It would also be very handy being able to debug test code with eclipse or intelliJ

Comment: The question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597102/how-to-force-logger-debug-output-in-play-framework-specs2-tests

Comment: Thanks Rajish, I misssed that one...