# Logging in Unit Tests for Play 2.3

Tags: logging, playframework

Been struggling to get any logging output in unit tests in Play 2.3 using `Logger.error("an error")`. I've tried all of [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597102/how-to-force-logger-debug-output-in-play-framework-specs2-tests) which seem to be outdated.

The closest I got was with a `build.sbt` containing the following:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-Dlogger.resource=conf/test-logger.xml")
```

This causes the `test-logger.xml` file to configure the logger, but still I do not get output from any tests.

Has anyone had any success with this in Play 2.3?

**Temporary Workaround**

I'm currently using a quick util class to deal with this until it is fixed. Added here as it may be useful for someone else.

```java
public class Logger {

    public static void debug(String message) {
        System.out.println(String.format("[debug] %s", message));
    }

    public static void info(String message) {
        System.out.println(String.format("[info] %s", message));
    }

    public static void warn(String message) {
        System.out.println(String.format("[warn] %s", message));
    }

    public static void error(String message) {
        System.err.println(String.format("[error] %s", message));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Jamesinchina updated his answer (in the question I referenced) to support **Play Framework 2.3**:

> I edited the answer to remove play.Project which is removed in 2.3.x, but the remaining still works - we are currently using it in our project.

Adding a `conf/test-logger.xml` file and the following line in `build.sbt` does the trick:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dlogger.file=conf/test-logger.xml"
```

[Updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23264524/213707)

Comment: Alternatively, `javaOptions in Test += "-Dlogger.resource=test-logger.xml"` should also work

Comment: This is the wrong answer for Play 2.5+ See @Fabian's response below.

Answer (score 6):

Since Play 2.5 everything is configured only via logback so we can rely on the default logback mechanisms to find the configs: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html.

This means that inside the `<project_or_module>/test/resources` folder one can place a file called `logback-test.xml` which takes precedence over the default `logback.xml` since both are on the class path when running tests.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add this to your build.sbt:

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v", "-q")

Check this page: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/WiqpjWZ_Qt0

Comment: This provides better output to console, but does not include logging output when using `play.Logger.error("a error")` - even with `testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-Dlogger.resource=test-logger.xml")` included as well.

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what the OP was asking for, but close enough, and was what I was looking for, and google led me to this QA.. so cudos earnt :)